# Can a function accept two values in flutter/dart language? if yes than how?

Tags: flutter, dart

Suppose I have a application with login function there are two text input field Username & Password. and there is on button called Login. Now if user enters Username and password and hit Login button then app will navigate him/her to next page like account page. But if user pressed login button with any or both field empty than a tooltip will called like "username & password cant be empty"...So i think login button will call a function (when pressed) which required two values username & password and if this values are empty then tooltip called otherwise navigate to next page...
Well, I am new to programming so maybe my whole logic can be wrong, and if logic is ok then what can I do??

Here is my code...

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:login_signup/accountpage.dart';

void main(List<String> args) {
  runApp(logsign());
}

class logsign extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _logsignState createState() => _logsignState();
}

class _logsignState extends State<logsign> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      routes: {
        '/account': (context) => AccountPage(),
      },
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.green,
      ),
      title: "logsignApp",
      home: homepage(),
    );
  }
}

class homepage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _homepageState createState() => _homepageState();
}

class _homepageState extends State<homepage> {

  String usrname;
  String passwd;

  void detailsmust (String usrname, passwd){
    if (usrname == "" || passwd == ""){
      Tooltip(message: "Username & Password field cant be empty");
    }
    else{
      Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/account')
    }
  }
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Login/Signup"),
      ),
      drawer: Text("Just a drawer", textScaleFactor: 2.0),
      body:
       Column(
         mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
         children: [
           TextField(
             onChanged: (text){
               usrname = text;
             },
             maxLength: 30,
             decoration: InputDecoration(
               prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.account_box),
               labelText: 'Username',
               border: OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0)),
             ),
           ),
            // Padding(
            //   padding: EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
            // ),
           TextField(
             onChanged: (text){
               passwd = text;
             },
             obscureText: true,
             decoration: InputDecoration(
               prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.lock_outline),
               labelText: 'Password',
               border: OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0)),
             ),
           ),
           Row(
             mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
             children: [
               MaterialButton(
              onPressed: detailsmust,
             child: Text("Login"),
             color: Colors.green,
             shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
           ),
           Padding(
             padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
           ),
           MaterialButton(
             onPressed: (){},
             child: Text("Exit"),
             color: Colors.green,
             shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
           ),
             ],
           ),
         ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to programming, you're logic is right. There are many ways to check for this value and functionality that you want. In Flutter you can use `TextField`s or `TextFormField`s which have `TextEditingControllers`, and `validators` and lots of other functionalities that you should look into. And these functionalities can indeed validate user input, and enable or disable certain functions such as logging in users as your case. What ever you can think of can be done. Start reading and working.

edit1:
Regarding the general purpose of your app, I would advise you to use it like this, when working with TextFields, make sure to remember that you have `TextEditingControllers` that would come in handy, thus, you should modify your submit function to look something like this:

```
TextEditingController usrname = TextEditingController();
TextEditingController passwd = TextEditingController();



void detailsmust() {
      if (usrname.text == "" || passwd.text == "") {
        setState(() {//setState is needed in order for the UI to change.
          Tooltip(message: "Username & Password field cant be empty");
        });
      } else {
        Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/account'); //was missing a semicolon here
      }
    }
```

And in your textFields, you don't have to use the on changed now, just point to your controllers, like this:

```
//for userName
TextField(
maxLength: 30,
controller:usrname
//rest of your textfields as they were
)

//for password
TextField(
controller:passwd
)
```

You don't have to declare the variables `String username` or `String passwd` anymore, and the text editing controllers willbe listening to the inputs of the fields.
To capture the values being held inside the controllers, you use the property `.text`, as in `username.text`.

Comment: Best thing you can do for yourself is up keep coding, and regarding asking on Stackoverflow the how to ask section, always post the code that you have written and the community will give back. Don't expect people to write code for you, but post where you are stuck and your exact problem. Happy coding.

Comment: Thank You for positive reply. It would be great if I can get more details like what syntax I can use or a sample code from your logic. I have little bit of knowledge about the widgets you told. Currently I am doing this steps for myapp
I created two textfields for username and password and stored their value as a string in variable "usrname" & "passwd". and I made a Materialbutton for Login which onpressed property is to call a function named "detailsrequired". Now I want to accepts "usrname" & "passwd" in this function so I can input a Tooltip and a navigator to next page. How can i do this?

Comment: I edited my post and uploaded my code. And I was not expecting anyone to write code for me. I just want to see an example like this so I can study more on that. Haha anyways thanks for reply I appreciate it. :)

Comment: wow thanks a lot for this. I didnt know about this functions. Now I can study more about this. Thanks again I appreciate it. :)